# how many 4 digit numbers can be formed from the digits 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 if the number must be even, start with 3, and have no repetitions?

Tags: combinatorics

how many 4 digit numbers can be formed from the digits 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 if the number must be even, start with 3, and have no repetitions?

i’ve got 1x7x6 so far, because three must be the first number. i’m stuck on whether the last number will be x4 or something else for the even because of the no repetitions.

combinatorics is my least favourite topic

Comment: Choose the last digit before choosing central digits: $1\times 4\times 7\times 6$

Answer (score 0):

Break apart by multiplication principle / rule of product, and recognize that we *do not have to have our steps refer to the digits from left to right!*  We can have our steps refer to the digits in whatever order we wish.

- Step 1:  Pick the first digit.  It must be a $3$, so there is only one option.
- Step 2: Pick the last digit.  It must be even, so there are $4$ options.
- Step 3: Pick the second digit.  It cannot be either a $3$ or whatever was picked in the previous step, so there are $7$ remaining options.
- Step 4: Pick the third digit.  It cannot be either a $3$ or whatever was picked in the previous two steps, so there are $6$ remaining options.

The answer is then the product of the number of options available for each step:

$$1\times 4\times 7\times 6 = 168$$